# Is the www-data user pre-configured in Linux and Unix systems?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, users, nginx, distributions

I personally usually use Debian based systems but I ask the following question on the entire *nix family of operating systems.

Is the `www-data` user usually using as the Apache/Nginx already comes with some *nix systems or is it usually created by a given software, i.e Apache/Nginx?

If it already comes with some systems (Debian in my case) it will prevent me for creating it for software different than Apache/Nginx before I install Apache/Nginx that might create it themselves, thus saving myself from some possible conflict.

BTW, I was thinking using it for Ansible with `become: yes`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you’re using Ansible, you should specify that you want a `www-data` user to be present, using [the user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html) with `state=present` and whatever other attributes are appropriate (*e.g.* `system=yes`). That will create the user if necessary, and won’t if one is already present. That’s a general principle of configuration management — describe the situation you want the system to be in, not the steps to get there.

On Debian, and presumably most derivatives, the `www-data` user is [always present](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/blob/master/passwd.master), it’s not created by a specific package for its own purposes (it’s [“created” by `base-passwd`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#uid-and-gid-classes), along with all the other entries in the default `/etc/passwd`). I don’t know off-hand about other systems.

Comment: Nice list of users that some I should get to know more personally and nice tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On Red Hat distributions and derivatives, typically the package installer has a "create user" command inside the pre-install script.  So, on CentOS 7, via the `rpm -q --scripts httpd` we can see

```
preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
# Add the "apache" group and user
/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 48 -r apache 2> /dev/null || :
/usr/sbin/useradd -c "Apache" -u 48 -g apache \
        -s /sbin/nologin -r -d /usr/share/httpd apache 2> /dev/null || :
```

This tells us a number of things:

- On Red Hat and derivatives the user is called `apache`
- It also tries to create a group called `apache`
- It wants the userid and groupid to be 48
- But if the user or group already exist then it continues with the install.